# Python: take a list of values of parameter from a list of namedtuple

Tags: python, list, namedtuple

I have a list of `namedtuples`, as an example below:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Example = namedtuple('Example', ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'])
e1 = Example(1,2,3)
e2 = Example(0,2,3)
e3 = Example(1,0,0)
e4 = Example(1,2,3)
e5 = Example(2,3,5)
full_list = [e1, e2, e3, e4, e5]
```

I would like to take a list of all values of a given parameter among the elements in the list, thus for example: for param '`arg1`' to have a `list  [1,0,1,1,2]` and for param '`arg2`' to have a `list [2,2,0,2,3]`

If I know the parameter in advance I can make it using a for loop, as

```
values = []
for e in full_list:
    values.append(e.arg1)
```

But how can I write a universal function which I can use for any parameter?

Comment: `values.append(e.__getattribute__("arg1"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) if you want to get it by the attribute name or [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) if you want to access it by "position":

```
>>> import operator

>>> list(map(operator.attrgetter('arg1'), full_list))
[1, 0, 1, 1, 2]

>>> list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), full_list))
[2, 2, 0, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to access the named attribute given the attribute as a string:

```
def func(param, lst):
   return [getattr(x, param) for x in lst]

print func('arg2', full_list)
# [2, 2, 0, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, there is a [`built-in function`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html) that enables access to attributes via their name, it is call [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#getattr) (there is also a similar setter function: [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#setattr)).

Its signature is getattr(object, name).

In your case, I suggest this:

```
attribute_list = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
Example = namedtuple('Example', attribute_list)
e1 = Example(1,2,3)
e2 = Example(0,2,3)
e3 = Example(1,0,0)
e4 = Example(1,2,3)
e5 = Example(2,3,5)
full_list = [e1, e2, e3, e4, e5]

values = []
for e in full_list:
    for attr in attribute_list:
        values.append(attr)
```